# Displays data divided into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of data and I want to display them no matter the order but by a particular order of columns for example 3

```
id
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14


id1 id2 id3
1   6   11
2   7   12
3   8   13
4   9   14
5   10  NULL
```

[Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5r0LP.png)

Comment: Are you saying you could have a variable number of columns or will it always be 3? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Formatting results for display purposes is a task better done in the client app rather than T-SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky.  One approach uses *two* calls to `ROW_NUMBER`, one for the row position and the other for the column position.  The logic here is that each row belongs to a group which rolls over as the `id` increases by multiples of 5, while the column is determined by how many multiples of 5 the `id` value represents.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id,
        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) - 1) / 5 AS rn1,
        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) - 1) % 5 AS rn2
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    rn2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn1 = 0 THEN id END) AS id1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn1 = 1 THEN id END) AS id2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn1 = 2 THEN id END) AS id3
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    rn2
ORDER BY
    rn2;
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions and conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when seqnum % 3 = 1 then id end),
       max(case when seqnum % 3 = 2 then id end),
       max(case when seqnum % 3 = 0 then id end)       
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by (seqnum - 1) / 3
```